# Convert JSON to a list of maps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to wrap some JSON in a response entity in order to pass it. The JSON looks like this:

```
{"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]},"body":"\"[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"BFF\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"10713436\\\"}...
```

If I call $.parseJSON(thatthing.body), I get:

```
[{"name":"BFF","id":"10713436"},...
```

which looks good -- like a list of maps, which is what I expect. But If I call $.parseJSON(thatthing.body)[0], I just get the character '[' -- the literal first character of that text.

How do I instead treat this object like the list of maps that it is?

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @elclanrs Gladly. Can you show me how I can do that, noting that I barely understand the basics of html and javascript?

Comment: Try jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen, there are a bunch of options.

Comment: @Jeremy Go to http://jsfiddle.net and paste relevant code in the appropriate sections, then click Save and edit your question with the button under the question's tags.

Comment: `thatthing.body` is a string that contains a string containing JSON. You have to parse twice. **Better**: Fix the code that generates this mess.

Comment: @FelixKling Ugh... thanks. Yes, I was actually encoding it as json twice without noticing. How could you tell?

Comment: `"\"[{\\\"`: It's a string (first `"`), which contains another string (`\"`) which contains JSON (`[{\\\"`). Also, since you said that `$.parseJSON(thatthing.body)[0]` returns `[`, it means that `$.parseJSON(thatthing.body)` returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats happening is $.parseJSON is giving you a string, just parse it back into an object.

```
var Jstring = $.parseJSON(thatthing.body);
var Jobject = JSON.parse(Jstring); //<-- parse the sting back into json
```

Comment: To be clear: `$.parseJSON` parses JSON and returns whatever the JSON decodes to. In this case it's a string. There is also no reason to use `$.parseJSON` and `JSON.parse`. Just use one of them.